# How to insulate exposed brick interior in Michigan

Tags: drywall, insulation, brick, spray-foam

I have a study room that extends from our brick colonial that took in some water a couple years back during a nasty storm. I’m in SE Michigan. I had to tear out all the wood paneling and insulation, and furring strips. Three of the four walls had insulation and the other wall is just the back of our chimney.

I’ve monitored the area being exposed for over a year now and see no water coming in, I think it was just a one time thing because the storm was so bad.

I’m looking to put up drywall instead of wood paneling on the three walls and leave the chimney brick exposed. Do I need to put a vapor barrier on the three walls before adding new furring strips? Or can I just put insulation against the brick like before? I read that I may want to use an inch or so of closed cell spray foam insulation directly against the brick.

Comment: vapor barrier is recommended

Comment: "an inch or so of closed cell spray foam" is both a vapor barrier and an air sealer. If that's affordable you do that, no questions asked.

Comment: The trick may be getting *only* an inch or so of spray foam!